# How to override the generic "Could not be found" msg for the app doesn't exist on the market

Tags: android, google-play

In my app, I'd like to put an Android market link which points to a future version of the app doesn't exist yet.

startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.mystuff.future_app")));

Currently, if user click the button, Android will show "The requested item could not be found" message.

Instead of this generic message, I'd like to show a customized message --- "Coming soon... please stay tuned".

How can i catch this error and override the message?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the behavior of the application that processes the intent.

Instead, why not just have that message in your app?  When you actually upload the other app, then you can update your original app to point to the download location.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot update the original app later because people already downloaded the original app as it goes out the market first.

Comment: So, you were saying that we cannot do startActivityForResult() on the Intent?  Can I receive some message back from the Market?

Comment: Right, but the market has provisions for updating an app.  You can only use startActivityForResult and get a response if the Market supports that.  Even then, the market activity is going to have already shown the dialog.